# SQLite query for ordering a list based on mistakes made

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I would like to know how to query a database based on the amount of mistakes made by a waiter.

The two tables I have are

**Employee**

```
    String employeeTable = "CREATE TABLE " + EMP_TABLE + " ("
            + ID_EMP + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + LAST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + PROFIT + " INTEGER);";
```

**MistakeEmployee**

```
    String mistakeTable = "CREATE TABLE " + MISTAKE_TABLE + " ("
            + ID_MISTAKE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + ID_WAITER_MISTAKE + " INTEGER,"
            + ID_ORDER_MISTAKE + " INTEGER,"
            + MISTAKE_TOTAL + " INITGER,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY (" + ID_WAITER_MISTAKE + ") REFERENCES " + EMP_TABLE + "(" + ID_EMP + "), "
            + " FOREIGN KEY (" + ID_ORDER_MISTAKE + ") REFERENCES " + ORDER_TABLE + "(" + ID_ORDER + "));";
```

I am trying to order the list based on the `Employee` with the most `Mistakes` which would be counted in the mistakes table using the `ID_WAITER_MISTAKE`.

```
String query = SELECT * , COUNT(Mistake_TABLE.ID_Waiter) as Count
FROM EMP_TABLE
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the tables, group by employee and aggregate:

```
SELECT e.ID_EMP, e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME,
       COUNT(m.ID_MISTAKE) AS Mistake_Count
FROM employeeTable e LEFT JOIN mistakeTable m
ON m.ID_WAITER_MISTAKE = e.ID_EMP
GROUP BY e.ID_EMP, e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME
ORDER BY Mistake_Count DESC, e.ID_EMP
```

and in Java code you should construct the sql string like this:

```
String query = 
    "SELECT e." + ID_EMP + ", e." + FIRST_NAME + ", e." + LAST_NAME + ", " + 
    "COUNT(m." + ID_MISTAKE + ") AS Mistake_Count " +
    "FROM " + EMP_TABLE + "AS e LEFT JOIN " + MISTAKE_TABLE + " AS m " +
    "ON m." + m.ID_WAITER_MISTAKE + " = e." + ID_EMP + " " +
    "GROUP BY e." + ID_EMP + ", e." + FIRST_NAME + ", e." + LAST_NAME + " " +
    "ORDER BY Mistake_Count DESC, e." + ID_EMP ;
```

I hope there are no typos.

Comment: Thanks I was halfway through doing this java conversion and yours works exactly what I was looking for